Reference request for self-duality/Gorenstein claim?
I am reading Mark Green's "Generic Initial Ideals". On page 134, he gives an example of an impossible candidate minimal free resolution $E_\bullet$ of an ideal $K\subseteq S:=\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ as:
\begin{align*}
E_0 &= S^2(-2)\oplus S^2(-3)\oplus S(-5)\\
E_1 &= S^4(-4)\oplus S(-6)\\
E_2 &= S(-7).
\end{align*}
He points out that the $E_2$ term forces $S/K$ to be Gorenstein, and therefore the $E_1$ and $E_0$ terms must be dual to each other after an appropriate twist. They are not, so such an ideal cannot exist.
I admit I am not very familiar with Gorenstein rings, so I searched through the literature to find a reference for this characterization of Gorenstein rings. I found Corollary 21.16 in Eisenbud's big book which almost gives this characterization, but this assumes we already know $S/K$ is Cohen-Macaulay.
As such, I would appreciate a reference to aid my understanding of Gorenstein rings. In particular, if the last term in a minimal free resolution of an ideal $I$ is isomorphic to $S$, must $S/I$ be Gorenstein?

You need the hypothesis $S/K$ is Cohen-Macaulay as given in Eisenbud's book. Otherwise, a counterexample is given by $K=(x,y)\cap(z,w)=(xz,xw,yz,yw)\subseteq \mathbf C[x,y,z,w]$. The resolution of $S/K$ is given by
$$
0\to S(-4)\to S(-3)^4\to S(-2)^4 \to S\to S/K\to 0.
$$
(I used Macaulay2 to compute the resolution.)
But it is well-known that $S/K$ is not Cohen-Macaulay as $\operatorname{depth}(S/K)=1$, but $\dim(S/K)=2$.

Thank you for this example! Does this mean the claim is false, as in such an ideal $K$ could actually exist? $S/K$ would have to not be Cohen-Macaulay.

I was answering your question at the end. Regarding Green’s claim, I think the ideal he has in mind is Artinian, so $S/K$ is automatically CM. But I don’t have his notes with me, so I am not 100% sure what the context is.

Thank you, this was very helpful.

By the way @cqfd I think I understand now. We do assume $K$ is Artinian. The reason is because the ideal also is claimed to have the property that its generic initial ideal is zero-dimensional. Since $K$ and $\mathrm{in}(K)$ have the same Hilbert function, $K$ must also be zero-dimensional, and the claim follows. Thanks again.
